# Virtualbox上に立てたLinuxサーバとWindowsサーバのpingが通らない

Tags: linux, windows, network, virtualbox

VirtualBox上にLinuxマシンとWindowsマシンを構築し、それぞれに内部ネットワークを設定しましたが、pingがWindows→Linuxの片方しか通りません。また、下記のように対応しましたが、上手くできませんでした。何が原因かわかる方いらっしゃいませんか？

- Linux：RHEL7.9、Windows：Windows10
- 内部ネットワーク名は同一です。
- Linux側のfirewallは切っています。
- Windows側のファイヤウォールはipv4に対して接続を許可するよう設定しています。
- ipアドレスは静的に割り当てており、サブネットワーク、デフォルトゲートウェイについては同じになっていることを確認しております。

【Linux側】

```
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:34:ac:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 430sec preferred_lft 430sec
    inet6 fe80::e2e:f30a:fcda:8502/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

【Windows側】

```
イーサネット アダプター イーサネット 2:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::c776:7275:4de8:76f0%12
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.56.102
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .: 192.168.56.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 はデフォルトでは ping に応答しなかったはずです。
ファイアウォールのルールで ICMP の応答を許可してみてください。

参考:
https://n-archives.net/software/nwol/articles/how-to-allow-ping-response-in-windows10/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Windows Defender ファイアウォールにおけるIPv4の受信・送信規則は有効にしております。それでも上手く疎通できません。。。